# SNMP oids corresponding to CLI command

Tags: python, command-line-interface, snmp, mib, pysnmp

```
info configure xdsl line 1/1/1/2
```

output :

```
configure xdsl
#------------------------------
echo "xdsl"
#------------------------------
line 1/1/1/2
  service-profile 1
  spectrum-profile 1
  admin-up
  transfer-mode atm
exit
#------------------------------
```

This command is a cli command and i'm trying to find corresponding to snmp oids in MibBrowser but i can't find these keys. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to download the device constructor's private MIB file(s).

- look into the MIB database : http://www.oidview.com/mibs/detail.html
- Or try an adsl generic MIB : http://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/adslmib/

Most constructors use standard mibs for basic features, and private mibs 
for more custom or advanced features.